# Python mismatch with given arguments in method

Tags: python, constructor

I'm a Java developer currently trying to write my own Python library. I have most of the functionality (that I want) down, I'm just having trouble with some Python syntax intricacies. I thought I had working code but when I tried an example I got this error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 /Users/willkara/Development/GitHub/SakaiPy/Examples/Example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/willkara/Development/GitHub/SakaiPy/Examples/Example.py", line 14, in <module>
    site = Sak.getSakaiSite('1e420647-1dce-4dbb-a789-9dfae3ccc8d8')
  File "/Users/willkara/Development/GitHub/SakaiPy/SakaiPy/SakaiPy.py", line 28, in getSakaiSite
    return SakaiSite.SakaiSite(self, self.requester, siteid)
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

My goal is to have this base object `SakaiPy` that is the main class for the library that handles most of the high level logic.

I want user to be able to do this at the end after user imports the project.

```
SakaiPyObject = SakaiPy(connectioninfo)

site = SakaiPyObject.getSakaiSite('site id goes here')

announcements = site.getAnnouncements()
```

I have most of classes & functions setup, I just am having trouble with some of the differences between Python and Java in how they handle constructors/methods/imports.

This is my code for the SakaiPy object:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

from SakaiPy import RequestHandler
from SakaiPy.SakaiTools import SakaiSite

loginURL = "/direct/session?_username={0}&_password={1}"

session = requests.Session()


class SakaiPy(object):
    def __init__(self, connectioninfo):
        """Generate the session cookie"""

        self.baseURL = connectioninfo['baseURL']

        # Generate a session cookie & store it in the requesting session
        session.post(self.baseURL + loginURL.format(
            connectioninfo['username'],
            connectioninfo['password']
        ))

        self.requester = RequestHandler.RequestHandler(session, self.baseURL)

    def getSakaiSite(self, siteid):
        return SakaiSite.SakaiSite(self, self.requester, siteid)
```

For the RequestHandler object:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class RequestHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, session, url):
        self.baseUrl = url
        self.session = session

    """This class handles the login/cookie mechanisms and request generation."""

    def executeRequest(self, url):
        """Returns the JSON response from the specified URL."""

        response = self.session.get(self.baseURL + url)

        """If it is a good response, then return the content in json form for the Sakai Object.
           If it is a bad response, raise an exception.
        """
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
        else:
            response.raise_for_status()
```

And for the SakaiSite object:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



class SakaiSite(object):
    def __init__(self, rq, siteid):
        self.requester = rq
        self.siteid = siteid

    def getMemership(self):
        return self.requester.executeRequest('/direct/membership/site/{0}.json'.format(self.siteid))

    def getRoster(self):
        return self.requester.executeRequest('/direct/roster/site/{0}.json'.format(self.siteid))

    def getGradebook(self):
        return self.requester.executeRequest('/direct/gradebook/site/{0}.json'.format(self.siteid))

    def getNews(self):
        return self.requester.executeRequest('/direct/news/site/{0}.json'.format(self.siteid))

    def getCalendar(self):
        return self.requester.executeRequest('/direct/calendar/site/{0}.json'.format(self.siteid))

    def getAnnouncements(self):
        return self.requester.executeRequest('/direct/announcement/site/{0}.json'.format(self.siteid))

    def getForums(self):
        return self.requester.executeRequest('/direct/forums/site/{0}.json'.format(self.siteid))

    def getContents(self):
        return self.requester.executeRequest('/direct/content/site/{0}.json'.format(self.siteid))
```

and finally, here is the demo code I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from SakaiPy import SakaiPy

"""Say I want to get a list of all of the Calendars I have for a specific site. I'll write all the code first then explain each part."""

authInfo = {}
authInfo['baseURL'] = "https://sakai.rutgers.edu"

authInfo['username'] = "username"
authInfo['password'] = "password"

Sak = SakaiPy.SakaiPy(authInfo)
site = Sak.getSakaiSite('siteid')

site.getAnnouncements()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self is passed implicitly to constructors

so

```
return SakaiSite.SakaiSite(self, self.requester, siteid)
```

is really

```
return SakaiSite.SakaiSite(self,self, self.requester, siteid)
```

instead you should ommit the self argument as it will be passed implicitly

```
return SakaiSite.SakaiSite( self.requester, siteid)
```

Comment: Looks like that did it. Thanks!